# File Error:data may have been lost while giving hyperlinks

Tags: excel, perl, hyperlink

I am writing a code to generate excel using Spreadsheet::WriteExcel. 
I want to write the data into cells and give the hyperlink to it.
I did that. But while opening the file it shows warning saying file data may have been lost.

```
$Log_Sheet->write(12,0,'AA',$ERR_DESCR_Format );
$Log_Sheet->write_url(12, 0,  'internal:sheet3!A1'  );
```

I want to write the content and provide link without getting warning. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spreadsheet::WriteExcel, greatness though it is, hasn't been updated for several years, and to my knowledge it only supports the pre-Office 2007 extension of .xls.  I'd really recommend you upgrade to Excel::Writer::XLSX, which is McNamara's fabulous update to the open XML standard format (xlsx).

So, I can't say for sure because this error does not happen on Excel::Writer::XLSX, but my initial theory is you are writing two different values to the exact same cell (12, 0), so the one is essentially clobbering the other -- hence the warning.

If you do upgrade to Excel-Writer, the warning should disappear.  More importantly, if you want a hyperlink, you include the link and the friendly description all in the same call:

```
$worksheet->write_url(12, 0, 'internal:Sheet3!A1', 'Click Here!');
```

For what it's worth, I think the `write` method will also correctly interpret this as a link:

```
$worksheet->write(12, 0, 'internal:Sheet3!A1', 'Click Here!');
```

-- EDIT 12/21/2018 --

If want to do a hyperlink on a merged cell, one way to do it is to use Excel's hyperlink function:

```
my $merged = $workbook->add_format();
$worksheet->merge_range("A10:A11",
  qq{=hyperlink("#'Sheet3'!A1","Click Here!")},
  $merged);
```

Comment: `write_url` takes both label and link in one call in Spreadsheet::WriteExcel as well. I don't personally subscribe to "everyone should upgrade to Excel::Writer::XLSX" (though unfortunately the module author seems to), as XLS and XLSX are two discrete formats that require two different modules. Of course people should stop using the XLS format, but that's a separate matter.

Comment: Thanks guys. I didn't know that we can give both label and link in one call. I got the expected output with Spreadsheet::WriteExcel itself.

Comment: Any idea on how to Merge the cells and giving hyperlinks without getting File error?

Comment: @Grinnz -- I guess that's my point, about xls vs xlsx.  More than a decade, post-implementation, is there a reason to still use xlsx?  I don't treat it as a separate matter.

Comment: @NAVEENPRAKASH -- in Spreadsheet::WriteExcel, you merge the range and assign the value as a single action.  Check out https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#merge_range($first_row,-$first_col,-$last_row,-$last_col,-$token,-$format,-$utf_16_be)

Comment: @Hambone Thanks for the reply. I have merged and assigned the value in single action. I wanted to have hyperlink also in the same action. That I am unable to do.

Comment: Aah, I see now I get it.  It's the combination of merged cell and hyperlink that's doing it.  See my update.  If you use the excel `hyperlink` function, it should do the trick.  Let me know.