# Merging the cells in excel and giving the hyperlink using Spreadsheet::WriteExcel

Tags: excel, perl, hyperlink

I am using Spreadsheet::WriteExcel. I want to merge two cells and give the hyperlink to the content inside merged cells.

I have tried like this.

```
$Log_Sheet->merge_range('D2:E2','Home',$MergedFormat);
$Log_Sheet->write_url('D2','internal:sheet1!A1');
```

This is working fine but when I try to open a file it shows a warning saying File error: data may have been lost. This occurs because D2 cell is being overwritten.

How can I merge cells and give hyperlink in one call?

Answer (score 1):

I can't promise this works on Spreadsheet::WriteExcel, but it does on Excel::Writer::XLSX.  I'd encourage you to try it on Spreadsheet::WriteExcel.

With merged ranges, once you declare a format, you need to continue using it for that range and never use it for non-merged ranges.  So, if you take your code and add the tag and the format object:

```
$Log_Sheet->merge_range("D2:E2", 'Home', $MergedFormat);
$Log_Sheet->write_url('D2', 'internal:sheet1!A1', 'Click Me!', $MergedFormat);
```

It does appear to work...  on Excel::Writer::XLSX.  Sorry to keep referencing that.

Alternatively, per the previous post ([File Error:data may have been lost while giving hyperlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53863832/file-errordata-may-have-been-lost-while-giving-hyperlinks/53868756#53868756)), you can also use the built-in Hyperlink function within Excel:

```
my $merged = $workbook->add_format();
$worksheet->merge_range("A10:A11",
  qq{=hyperlink("#'Sheet3'!A1","Click Here!")},
  $merged);
```

Comment: Its not working in Spreadsheet::WriteExcel. It shows error as Unknown defined name Hyperlink in formula

Comment: Try HYPERLINK in all caps...  a guess, but worth a try.

Comment: This is also not Working.

Comment: Function must not be available on Spreadsheet::.  Have you tried option 1?

Comment: Yeah I tried both. It shows Unknown function HYPERLINK() in formula

Comment: What error message did the option *without* the hyperlink formula give you?  The first two lines of code, not the last four...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185598/discussion-between-naveen-prakash-and-hambone).

Comment: The first two lines works fine and I get the expected output. But while opening Excel file it shows an warning saying Data may have been lost.

Comment: You sure I can't talk you into upgrading to Excel::Writer::XLSX?

Comment: No. We are supposed to use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel only. Anyway thanks for your efforts. I have removed merging concept for time being.